# How do i disable buttons after logging out in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent app component that has a horizontal menu with different buttons in it. Each button makes a child component appear under the menu. When Logged-in the login button changes to logout.When I press logout it should take all the buttons out of the DOM again.I am having trouble achieving this. It sort of works when I use,

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

for the AppComponent class. However this is having the unpleasant side-effect of preventing any lists in the child components 
 retrieved from the database from rendering. Furthermore I have to reload the app with the code `location.reload()` for the buttons to disappear again.

When I don't use OnPush strategy I get the error

```
 "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'."
```

Can anyone tell me what I should change for it to work properly?

I use a service to enable the different components to communicate with one another.
Below is my code:

The app component

```
@Component({
  //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector:'app-root',
  templateUrl:'./app.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;
  isEnabledForUser: boolean = false;
  isEnabledForAdmin: boolean = false;

  //private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  //      this.ref.detectChanges()

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.title = "Verlofurenregistratie";
    loginService.loginSuccessful$.subscribe(val =>{
      console.log("received an new value")
      this.isEnabledForUser = val
      this.isEnabledForAdmin = false})
    loginService.adminLoginSuccessful$.subscribe(val =>{
      console.log("received an new value")
      this.isEnabledForAdmin = val;
      this.isEnabledForUser = val;
    })
    loginService.logout$.subscribe(val => {
      this.isEnabledForAdmin = val;
      this.isEnabledForUser = val;
    })
  }
}
```

the appcomponent HTML

```
<header class="page-header">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/login']">{{!(isEnabledForAdmin || isEnabledForUser) ? "Login" : "Logout"}}</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/account/create']">Account aanmaken</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/account/list']">Account overzicht</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForUser" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/create']">Verlofuren aanvragen</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/list']">Verlofuren overzicht</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/pending']">Verlofaanvragen overzicht</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Berichten&hellip;</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The login child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [AccountService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  title: string;
  loggedIn: boolean = false;
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  error = '';
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private accountService: AccountService,
              private router: Router,
              private loginService: LoginService,
              private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.title = "Inloggen";
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    console.log("I'm in ngOnChanges right now..")
    if(localStorage.getItem("account") !== null){
      console.log("loggedIn is true")
      localStorage.clear()
      // this.ref.detectChanges()
      //this.loginService.onLogout()
       this.loginService.isLoginSuccessful(false, "user");
      //location.reload(false)
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {

  }

  onSubmit() {
    const formModel = this.loginForm.value;
    this.accountService.authenticate(formModel.email, formModel.password).then(account =>
    {
        if (account !== undefined && account.enabled) {
          localStorage.setItem("account",JSON.stringify(account))
          this.loggedIn = true;
      if(account.admin) {
        this.loginService.isLoginSuccessful(true, "admin");
        this.router.navigate(["leave/pending"])
      }
      else {
        this.loginService.isLoginSuccessful(true, "user");
        this.router.navigate(["leave/create"])
      }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The Login HTML

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"
           placeholder="naam@mail.com"
           formControlName="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control"
           formControlName="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Inloggen</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: You can make 2 separate buttons for login and logout and use *ngIf on them. This way only one button will appear at a time based on your conditions

Comment: Remember if you use ngIf, you don't have to tell Angular to detect changes. It changes the view dynamically based on the ngIf condition

Comment: and how do I remove the buttons after logging out? They shouldn't be visible in such a case

Answer (score -1):

In your appComponent.html, you can do this:

```
<header class="page-header">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a *ngIf="!(isEnabledForAdmin || isEnabledForUser)" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
        <a *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin || isEnabledForUser" [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/account/create']">Account aanmaken</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/account/list']">Account overzicht</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForUser" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/create']">Verlofuren aanvragen</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/list']">Verlofuren overzicht</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="isEnabledForAdmin" role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/pending']">Verlofaanvragen overzicht</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Berichten&hellip;</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: this isn't helping, The buttons should be removed after logout also.